# Parallel deserialization of Json from a database

Tags: json, c#-4.0, deserialization, task-parallel-library

This is the scenario: In a separate task I read from a datareader which represent a single column result set with a string, a JSON. In that task I add the JSON string to a BlockingCollection that wraps the ConcurrentQueue. At the same time in the main thread I TryTake/dequeue a JSON string from the collection and then yield return it deserialized.

The reading from the database and the deserialization is approximately of the same speed so there will not be to much memory consumption caused by a large BlockingCollection.

When the reading from the database is done, the task is closed and I then deserialize all the non deserialized JSON strings.

**Questions/thoughts:**

1) Does the TryTake lock so that no adding can be done?

2) Don't do it. Just do it in serial and yield return.

```
using (var q = new BlockingCollection<string>())
{
Task task = null;

try
{
    task = new Task(() =>
    {
        foreach (var json in sourceData)
            q.Add(json);
    });

    task.Start();

    while (!task.IsCompleted)
    {
        string json;
        if (q.TryTake(out json))
            yield return Deserialize<T>(json);
    }

    Task.WaitAll(task);
}
finally 
{
    if (task != null)
    {
        task.Dispose();
    }

    q.CompleteAdding();
}

foreach (var e in q.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    yield return Deserialize<T>(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1

> Does the TryTake lock so that no adding can be done

There will be a very brief period whereby an add cannot be performed, however this time will be negligible. From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305.aspx

> Some of the concurrent collection types use lightweight
>   synchronization mechanisms such as SpinLock, SpinWait, SemaphoreSlim,
>   and CountdownEvent, which are new in the .NET Framework 4. These
>   synchronization types typically use busy spinning for brief periods
>   before they put the thread into a true Wait state. When wait times are
>   expected to be very short, spinning is far less computationally
>   expensive than waiting, which involves an expensive kernel transition.
>   For collection classes that use spinning, this efficiency means that
>   multiple threads can add and remove items at a very high rate. For
>   more information about spinning vs. blocking, see SpinLock and
>   SpinWait.
>
> The ConcurrentQueue and ConcurrentStack classes do not use locks
>   at all. Instead, they rely on Interlocked operations to achieve
>   thread-safety.

Question 2:

> Don't do it. Just do it in serial and yield return.

This seems like the way to go. As with any optimisation work - do what is simplest and then measure! If there is a bottleneck here consider optimising, but at least you'll know if your 'optimistations' are actually helping by virtue of having metrics to compare against.

Comment: Measurements will be hard. Sure I can test it and come to a conclusion on an certain environment against a certain type of JSON size, but the scenarios will vary very much. Could be one string could be 10000. Could be one property JSON structure could be 20 properties....

Comment: @Daniel Profilers will enable you to see the amount of time spent in each block of code. If you have a suitable environment, replicating live usage should not be a problem.

Comment: Yeah I know profilers will, it's the amount of possible scenarios that is hard to foresee.

Comment: Sorry, don't mean to sound harsh, but about the locking "believe" or "know"?